# Model not updating when using a service with $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an idea why it's not working, but not exactly how to fix this, and I've looked at the various similar questions/answers on SO but I can not fix my issue.

I am trying to call a service on page load to list a table of data, or let's just call this a  list of urls.

The model would simply be `{ urls }` would should return an array of urls, where in the future I'd use ng-repeat.

My controller:

```
function UrlListCtrl($scope, UrlService){
  $scope.urls = UrlService.getUrls();
}
```

Service:

```
function UrlService($http) {
  return {
    getUrls: getUrls
  }
  function getUrls() {
    console.log('Fetching Urls...');
    return $http.get('urls/get')
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log('response:', response.data);
        this.urlsResults = response.data;
    });
  }
}
```

The service does run, however it doesn't update the view. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[$http.get()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is an async operation that returns a promise. You have to wait for this promise to be fulfilled, and then you can get the data from the response.

In your code `$scope.urls = UrlService.getUrls();` was assigning the promise, and not it's results to `$scope.urls`, and the view was never updated when the operation ended.

Controller:

```
function UrlListCtrl($scope, UrlService){
  UrlService.getUrls().then(function(response) {
     $scope.urls = response.data;
  });
}
```

Service:

```
function UrlService($http) {
  return {
    getUrls: getUrls
  }
  function getUrls() {
    console.log('Fetching Urls...');
    return $http.get('urls/get');
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Read the link about $http, as it contains lots of useful information. Also read about [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), so you'll understand angular promises.